# RolDWord Implementation in Delphi (both 32 and 64 bit)?

Tags: delphi

According to 
http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/roldword.html

RolDWord rotates a 4-byte int to the left (Free Pascal).

is there RolDWord in Delphi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use these functions:

```
function rolw(Value: Word; N: Integer): Word;
asm
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROL  AX, CL
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
  MOV  AX, CX
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROL  AX, CL
{$ELSE}
{$Message Fatal 'rolw has not been implemented for this architecture.'}
{$ENDIF}
end;

function rorw(Value: Word; N: Integer): Word;
asm
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROR  AX, CL
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
  MOV  AX, CX
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROR  AX, CL
{$ELSE}
{$Message Fatal 'rorw has not been implemented for this architecture.'}
{$ENDIF}
end;

function roldw(Value: Cardinal; N: Integer): Cardinal;
asm
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROL  EAX, CL
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
  MOV  EAX, ECX
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROL  EAX, CL
{$ELSE}
{$Message Fatal 'roldw has not been implemented for this architecture.'}
{$ENDIF}
end;

function rordw(Value: Cardinal; N: Integer): Cardinal;
asm
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROR  EAX, CL
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
  MOV  EAX, ECX
  MOV  CL, DL
  ROR  EAX, CL
{$ELSE}
{$Message Fatal 'rordw has not been implemented for this architecture.'}
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

However, as [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650492/johan) and [LU RD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576719/lu-rd) point out, an inline Pascal version is portable and usually faster for this function due to the benefit of inlining being so significant for such a small function.

That looks like this:

```
{$IFOPT Q+}{$DEFINE OVERFLOWCHECKSON}{$ENDIF}
{$Q-}    
function rolw_pas(Value: Word; N: Integer): Word; inline;
begin
  Result:= ((Value shl N) and $ffff) or (Value shr (16-N));
end;

function rorw_pas(Value: Word; N: Integer): Word; inline;
begin
  Result:= (Value shr N) or ((Value shl (16-N)) and $ffff);
end;

function roldw_pas(Value: Cardinal; N: Integer): Cardinal; inline;
begin
  Result:= (Value shl N) or (Value shr (32-N));
end;

function rordw_pas(Value: Cardinal; N: Integer): Cardinal; inline;
begin
  Result:= (Value shr N) or (Value shl (32-N));
end;
{$IFDEF OVERFLOWCHECKSON}{$Q+}{$ENDIF}
```

Note that we do need to makes sure that overflow checking is disabled.

Comment: Why not include the purepascal version?

Comment: @Johan I originally had a Pascal version but I think I changed because it somehow felt cleaner to use the instruction provided by the hardware.

Comment: It seems the purepascal solution is faster. See my comment on Johan's answer.

Comment: @LURD that's interesting. I'd like to see benchmark code though. Always possible that the benchmark was wrong. Not expecting that to be the case of course.

Comment: var
  sw: TStopWatch;
  dw,dw1: DWord;
  i: Integer;
begin
  dw := 2;
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 1 to 1000000000 do begin
    dw1 := roldw( dw,31);
  end;
  WriteLn(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, ' ',dw1);
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 1 to 1000000000 do begin
    dw1 := roldwPPInline( dw,31);
  end;
  WriteLn(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, ' ',dw1);
  ReadLn;
end.

Comment: I think your version could be faster if you replace the MOV CL, DL with MOV ECX,EDX this prevents a partial register update and should fix a false dependency issue (on some processors). More generally never use byte registers unless you actually need to preserve the upper bits of the register.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look at this when I get a chance later.

Comment: @Johan It doesn't make much difference so far as I can tell to use `MOV ECX,EDX`

Comment: @LURD Try this variant though, not so clear cut: `var
  sw: TStopWatch;
  dw: Cardinal;
  i: Integer;

begin
  dw := 2;
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 1 to 1000000000 do
  begin
    dw := roldw(dw, i);
  end;
  WriteLn(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, ' ', dw);
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 1 to 1000000000 do
  begin
    dw := roldw_pas(dw, i);
  end;
  WriteLn(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, ' ', dw);
  ReadLn;

end.
` But yes, Pascal seems to be a better choice.

Comment: @Johan Not needing to fight with overflow checking is another reason to use asm

Comment: Calling `roldw_pas( dw,33);` gives `E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds`. It is the inlining that makes the compiler behave erratic. It should respect the overflow checking option before giving up. Compiler bug?

Comment: @LURD I was going change my own libraries to use Pascal versions but changed my mind after discovering overflow checks issues. For desktop compilers it's just simpler to use asm I think.

Answer (score 3):

In purepascal you can use shifts as follows.

```
function rolw(input: dword; shift: cardinal): dword; inline;
begin
  Result:= (input shl shift) or (input shr (32-shift));
end;
```

RorW works exactly the same.

**Benefits**
It will work in any version of Delphi including the mobile compilers.

The asm code is actually slower, because it cannot be inlined, according to LURD's timings (on his system, and his input data) the pure pascal version is 3.5x faster on x86 and 25% faster on x64. But with different input data the timings can be radically different, so if performance is a driving factor, make sure you benchmark with data representative of you actual problem.

The source is shorter, because you don't need different versions for different CPU types.

If you have a bigger block of asm by all means use the ror/rol instructions; they have the exact same latency as a shift instruction, but do the deed in 1 instruction not 3.

Comment: The perf will be faster on the single op I believe, rather than inline three op

Comment: The 1 asm op is really 3 ops: call asm routine; ror; ret. The call flushes one entry out of the return-prediction-stack (usually 6 to 8 deep (2 on atom). The call will incur delays if situation is not optimal. The 3 statements do not suffer from this.

Comment: If shift is > 32 you may need `shift := shift mod 32` as well.

Comment: For x32, the purepascal solution is 3.5 times faster while in x64 it is 25% faster.

Comment: @LU I think shl 33 is the same as shl 1 right? Funny x86 implementation detail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, correct, but what is shr -1? Haven't tested yet.

Comment: @LURD I think the hardware masks the bottom 6 bits and uses that for the shift. So shr -1 is shr 31.

Comment: @Johan Take the timings with a pinch of salt. Don't report timings without a benchmark program and a statement of the input data. A minor change to input data and the timings are completely different.

Comment: Try the LURD's benchmark, and then my variant. Interesting to see the huge difference between the two benchmarks.